# sqlKata, parameter count mismatch on InsertGetId<>

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlkata

I am trying to insert a row (working version)

```
     _masterDb.Query(table.FullName()).Insert(value.ForDatabase);
     //raw sql: 
     //INSERT INTO [mst].[TableOne] ([Name], [TableCol]) VALUES ('www', 'ddf')
```

But if I want to fetch `Id` of last inserted row

```
     _masterDb.Query(table.FullName()).InsertGetId<int>(value.ForDatabase);
     //raw sql: 
     //INSERT INTO [mst].[TableOne] ([Name], [TableCol]) VALUES ('www', 'ddf'); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as Id
```

For this, I get error `Parameter count mismatch`?? Where is the parameter mismatch?

**Note**: If I copy paste the aboe Raw SQL generate, it does work.

Comment: could you post the `SqlResult.RawSql` and the `SqlResult.Bindings`?